# XMLHttpRequest doesn’t work while submitting a form ”Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Just now i came to know that,  ”XMLHttpRequest doesn’t work while submitting a form (useful for progress tracking)” in Chrome/Safari due to Webkit Bug 23933. But i'm using this technique, that is i am submitting a form which content some multipart data(file upload) then through ajax request ( in specific interval) i'm trying get the status from server.

This working fine in FF but not in chrome, What i should do , I want to show some in formation and status during , multiple file upload. What should I do, I get about this information from 
this site :- http://chemicaloliver.net/programming/php-5-4-file-upload-progress-and-html5-progress-bars/

Comment: Try submitting the form using XHR2 (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/). Or submit the form to a hidden iframe and redirect on iframe.onload.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I was so much busy in other task, By the way the XHR2 is working in FF and chrome only not in Safari. You second solution, i was bit confuse , can you give some code example for submitting the form to hidden iframe.

Comment: XHR2 should work as of Safari 5.1. As for the iFrame solution: `<iframe id="upload" onload="..." />...<form target="upload" ...>...`